# SQL Workbench/J and BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, sql-workbench-j

I am currently using SQL Workbench/J as my GUI to interface and run queries for BigQuery, however I'm running into a 10 second timeout issue when running more complicated queries. Any advice on how to increase the default timeout limit? Is it accessible/changeable from within the GUI? The error message I'm receiving is this:

> [Simba]BigQueryJDBCDriver The job has timed out on the server. Try increasing the timeout value. [SQL State=HY000, DB Errorcode=100034]

(PS: I set up SQL Workbench/J using [these steps](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sql-workbench/YVanBRKmOiE) and [this driver](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/partners/simba-drivers/))

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you define the [ConnectionString](http://cdn.simba.com/products/BigQuery/doc/JDBC_InstallGuide/content/jdbc/bq/using/connectionurl.htm) you are able to add [driver properties](http://cdn.simba.com/products/BigQuery/doc/JDBC_InstallGuide/content/jdbc/bq/options/intro-general.htm). [Timeout](http://cdn.simba.com/products/BigQuery/doc/JDBC_InstallGuide/content/jdbc/bq/options/timeout.htm) is one of the properties you can use.

Simply add:

```
jdbc:bigquery://...;Timeout=3600;
```