# How do to increase timeout value for DataGrip's connection to Google BigQuery?

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, ide, datagrip

I currently connect JetBrain's DataGrip IDE to Google BigQuery to run my queries. I get the following error however: `[Simba][BigQueryJDBCDriver](100034) The job has timed out on the server. Try increasing the timeout value.`  This of course happens when I run a query that may take some time to execute.

I can execute queries that take a short amount of time to complete so the connection does work.

I looked at this question ([SQL Workbench/J and BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42986867/sql-workbench-j-and-bigquery)) but I still did not fully understand how to change the timeout value

The error is seen below in this screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Have you seen [changing the timeout value](https://forum.knime.com/t/from-bigquery-how-to-increase-the-timeout-value/32448/6)? But if you have further questions you can [contact simba support](https://www.magnitude.com/about-us/contact).

Answer (score 3):

This works well also:

Datasource Properties | Advanced | Timeout : 3600

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Please open up data source properties and add this to the very end of connection URL: `;Timeout=3600;` (note it case sensitive). Try to increase the value until error is gone.